# Does SingleThreadExecutor guarantee thread safety?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, executorservice

I have a following class:

```
class Broker {
    private final List<StorageDevice> storageDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    private AtomicInteger flag = new AtomicInteger(0);

    //storageDevices initialization omitted

    public void push(Item item, int id) {
        storageDevices.get(id).submit(item);

    }

    class StorageDevice{
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        void submit(Item item){
            executor.execute(() -> {
                if(flag.incrementAndGet()>1)
                    throw new IllegalStateException("More than one!");
                    //some additional work
                if(flag.decrementAndGet()>0)
                    throw new IllegalStateException("More than zero!");
            })
        }
    } 
}
```

Class **Broker** is used by many threads that concurrently call **push** method. Although, I have a single thread executor and **List storageDevices** is being only red, I get **IllegalStateException("More than one!")** indicating that **executor** is executing more than one task in the same time.

Could someone please explain what is happening here and how to achieve thread safety in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You has a `List<StorageDevice>`. Each element has its own `ExecutorService`, and each `ExecutorService` executes one thread.

So you have multiple threads (one per element of the list), and all are incrementing and decrementing the same flag concurrently.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need another coffee. How could I not see this?